# boost library in microsoft c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

i am using  microsoft visual c++ 2010  can i  use boost library or does it  requires different compiler?

Answer (score 5):

From the [most recent version of Boost's release notes:](http://www.boost.org/users/download/version_1_43_0)

- Linux:

  - Intel 10.1, 11.1 on 32 bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
  - Intel 10.1, 11.0, 11.1 on 64 bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
  - GCC 3.4.6, 4.2.4, 4.3.4, 4.4.3 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
  - GCC 4.3.4, 4.4.3 with C++0x extensions on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
  - QLogic PathScale(TM) Compiler Suite: Version 3.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
- OS X:

  - Intel C++ Compiler 10.1, 11.0, 11.1 on Leopard.
  - GCC 4.0.1 on Intel Leopard.
  - Clang from subversion.
- Windows:

  - Visual C++ 8,0, 9,0 on 32-bit XP.
  - Visual C++ 9.0 using STLport 5.2 on XP and Windows Mobile 5.0.
  - **Visual C++ 10.0 on XP.**
  - **Visual C++ 10.0 on 64-bit Windows 7.**
  - Borland/Codegear C++ 5.9.3, 6.1.3 (2009), 6.2.1 (2010).
  - Intel C++ 11.1, with a Visual C++ 9.0 backend, on Vista 32-bit.
  - GCC 4.3.3 on Mingw.
  - GCC 4.4.3 on Mingw, with and without C++0x extensions.
  - GCC 4.5 on Mingw.
- AIX:

  - IBM XL C/C++ Enterprise Edition, V10.1.0.0, on AIX Version 5.3.0.40.
- FreeBSD:

  - GCC 4.2.1 on FreeBSD 7.2, 64 bit.
  - GCC 4.2.1 on FreeBSD 8.0, 32 bit.
- Solaris:

  - Sun C++ 5.10 on Solaris 5.10.

Answer (score 2):

Boost is basically an C++ extension. It compiles with every standard compliant c++ compiler.

Comment: This is a Zen answer.  Now, is MSDEV 2010 a standards compliant C++ compiler?  It depends...

Comment: +1. Nitpick: Considering there are no compilers which are completely standards conformant, I'd change that to "every *reasonably* standards compliant C++ compiler."

Comment: Well I guess that some day Boost will be the standard anyway. The problem is what is first Standard or Boost??

Comment: Boost is a library (or a collection of libraries), not a language extension :)

Comment: @jalf: I come from C# were there is a big standard library. I miss that thing in C++. The philosophy seems to be to separate language from standard libray. I find it handy to have both together and fiting to each other:) But yes you are right!

Comment: @schoetbi: .NET is technically a OS extension, with a built-in compiler.  C++ most keeps the language/library separation with a few slips (new can throw an exception defined in the library)

Comment: Boost was created by member of the C++ Standardization Committee with the intension of creating libraries that might one day be added to the Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

Boost is tested against all major C++ compilers, including Visual C++

UPDATE: Krill found the Compilers Tested link before me, so I'll just add that Microsoft is a sponsor of Boost (I think the contributed compilers for testing), and several regular contributors to Boost have day-jobs at Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Check "Compilers Tested" section [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/version_1_43_0), Visual C++ in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!
Tried & working!